# Error: No component factory found for e. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

> 

I'm working on angular 8 project.I'm facing this issues in development..
in my local it's working properly but in  development I'm facing this issue
main.3a3da72728121fa90e44.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found for e. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
Error: No component factory found for e. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/We57y.png

Comment: is e defined as component in your code ?

Comment: no it's no defined in my code

Comment: can you please modify your question and give more information in which component this  issue is being observed?

Comment: I'm getting issues in every component in my project

Comment: while using in local it's working properly

Answer (score 1):

You don't give much information so I'm a little unsure if this is the correct fix.

However, you can try doing exactly what the error message says and add the component to the `entryComponents` array in your AppModule or relevant feature module:
[image]

If that doesn't fix the issue, then please show us the component files and explain what you're trying to do.